# SQL Server : I need to pass a row value as a parameter to table function in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, table-functions

I want to create a stored procedure with a table-valued function as a column.
I want to use one of the other column values as the parameter for the function.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AuditReportLeaseID]
    @leaseID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        a.assetID as Asset, a.Location, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.auditdate, 101) AS Date, 
        a.qtyaudit AS Qty, 
        c.classname AS Class, a.grade AS Grade, 
        a.serialnumber AS [S/N], 
        a.materialdescription AS Description, a.Notes, 
        (SELECT tf.AD 
         FROM fGetAuditDescrConcat(a.assetId) tf) AS AuditDescription   
    FROM
        audit a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ORDER_DETAILS od ON a.assetID = od.assetId
    INNER JOIN
        class c ON a.classid = c.classid 
    WHERE
        a.classID = c.classID 
        AND a.leaseID = @leaseID
    ORDER BY
        class, grade, a.materialDescription
END
```

This procedure will return multiple rows and I want to use the value of the first column `a.assetID` (which is a `varchar(64)`) as the parameter to the `fGetAuditDescrConcat` function.

Is this possible?

Comment: well what happens when you try it???

Comment: Sorry   - it does not let me compile the proc.   It is unhappy with the (a.assetid).      Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but I take it you might be looking for something like this:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AuditReportLeaseID]
     @leaseID int
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
   SELECT * FROM
    (Select a.assetID
      from audit a
      left outer join ORDER_DETAILS od on a.assetID=od.assetId
      inner join class c on a.classid=c.classid where a.classID = c.classID and a.leaseID = @leaseID
      Order by class,grade,a.materialDescription
    ) a
    CROSS APPLY fGetAuditDescrConcat(a.assetID)

    END
```

Comment: Thanks- I tried the above but it is still unhappy with the parameter for the function.  I get an error compiling 
"Invalid syntax near ".'."
Sorry I should have stated this in my original post   The main issue is with the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If your given query returns error like Subquery returns more than one row;

Try the modified on as below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AuditReportLeaseID]
    @leaseID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        a.assetID as Asset, a.Location, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.auditdate, 101) AS Date, 
        a.qtyaudit AS Qty, 
        c.classname AS Class, a.grade AS Grade, 
        a.serialnumber AS [S/N], 
        a.materialdescription AS Description, a.Notes, 
        (SELECT TOP 1 tf.AD 
         FROM fGetAuditDescrConcat(a.assetId) tf) AS AuditDescription   
    FROM
        audit a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ORDER_DETAILS od ON a.assetID = od.assetId
    INNER JOIN
        class c ON a.classid = c.classid 
    WHERE
        a.classID = c.classID 
        AND a.leaseID = @leaseID
    ORDER BY
        class, grade, a.materialDescription
END
```

Comment: Thanks- I tried the above but it is still unhappy with the parameter for the function.  I get an error compiling 
"Invalid syntax near ".'."
Sorry I should have stated this in my original post   The main issue is with the parameter.